# subsetting ABM results by endpoint

Tags: r

this is probably very easy but I could use some help... I've built an agent-based model that runs 300 times for an arbitrary number of steps, depending on what happens inside the model. the resulting data is structured like this:

[image]

I want to isolate the runs that end in 150 steps or less and analyze them in their entirety (not just the final step). what's the best way to do this in R? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand: what does the column `run` correspond to? and the column `step`?

Comment: run is an individual run of the model. each run generates between 100 and 300 steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `aggregate` to get the number of steps per run:

`n_steps <- aggregate(AT6$run, by=list(run=AT6$run), FUN=length)`

Now compute a filter variable:

`n_steps <- within(n_steps, filter <- x<=150)`

Merge with the original data and keep only filtered runs:

`AT6_f <- merge(AT6, n_steps)`

`AT6_f <- AT6_f[AT6_f$filter,]`

And finally split the data.frame by runs:

`result <- split(AT6_f, AT6_f$run)`

Note: the result is a list, each element being a data.frame containing a single run. If you have a function `f` that analyses each run, you should pass the result above to it with this:

`lapply(result, f)`